# Change the color of the series line dynamically by month

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have a series from Jan - Dec, the requirement is to update the last data point to grayscale colors. So I have created additional data series assigning grayscale colors to the series. Can I be able to join the colored series with grayscale colored series

http://jsfiddle.net/hgj7sfhp/33/

for example, London colored and London grayscale should be joined, like continuouss series after November, without any break in the series. I have London & Berlin in December points in the chart, but i wanted to attached to the colored series, is it possible ?

Also group the legend of colored series and grayscale series.

London, Berlin

LondonGray, BerlinGray

```
$(function () {
    var grayblue = '#1D1D1D';
    var grayred = '#4C4C4C';

    dataLondon = [ 48.9, 38.8, 39.3, 41.4, 47.0, 48.3, 59.0, 59.6, 52.4, 45.6, 90.4];
    dataBerlin = [ 42.4, 33.2, 34.5, 39.7, 52.6, 75.5, 57.4, 60.4, 47.6, 23.6, 29.1]
    highcharts(dataLondon, dataBerlin, 0);


    function highcharts(dataLondon, dataBerlin, number) {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'line'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Monthly Average Rainfall'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: [
                'Jan',
                'Feb',
                'Mar',
                'Apr',
                'May',
                'Jun',
                'Jul',
                'Aug',
                'Sep',
                'Oct',
                'Nov',
                'Dec'
            ],
            plotBands: { color: 'Red',
                from: 10.5,
                to: 10.55,
                        label: {
                            text: 'I am label'
                        }

            }
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'Rainfall (mm)'
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>',
            pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td>' +
                '<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y:.1f} mm</b></td></tr>',
            footerFormat: '</table>',
            shared: true,
            useHTML: true
        },
        colors: ['#0000FF', '#FF0000'],
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                pointPadding: 0.2,
                borderWidth: 0
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'London',
            data: dataLondon

        }, {
            name: 'Berlin',
            data: dataBerlin

        }, {
            name: 'London',
            data: [null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,10],
            color: '#1D1D1D'
        }, {
            name: 'Berlin',
            data: [null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null, 51.1],
            color: '#4C4C4C'
        }]
    });
    }
});
```

Comment: Sounds like something for two overlapping series with `linkedTo`.

Comment: @Ondkloss can you guide me to use `linkedTo` in my example ?

Comment: are you looking for http://jsfiddle.net/hgj7sfhp/37/? I have used marker inside series data against y value.

Comment: to connect with grey line, using linkedTo as Ondkloss suggested:  http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/hgj7sfhp/38/

Comment: @jlbriggs thanks, that is exactly what i am looking for, i would need the legend with gray colors. so they are independent of each other with select and deselect them

Comment: @jlbriggs I found that when i'm at Nov, I see 4 points in tooltip, can we hide one of them in the tooltip.

Comment: Yes, you can use [`tooltip.formatter`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.formatter).